# PDO Passing Parameters by Reference

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, parameters

I am attempting to create a function in PHP that will simplify access to my database using PDO. I have the follow code for the function:

```
/**
* This function accepts a variable as well as a SQL query and evaluates that SQL query against the variable utilizing the PDO class.
* There is no return because the variables are modified by reference location, thus allowing you to continue to use them.
*
* @param $container The variable that will act as a container to hold the result of the SQL query.
* @param $fetch The variable that will store an array of the query's resulting data.
* @param $fetchStatus A boolean value that will determine how data is fetched. A 0 with result in a fetch and 1 will result in a fetchAll.
* @param $SQL The SQL query you wish to execute against the database as a string.
*/
function dbQuery(&$container, &$fetch, $fetchStatus, $SQL) {
    global $dbMain;

    $container = $dbMain->prepare($SQL);
    $container->execute();

    if($fetchStatus == 0) {
        $fetch = $container->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
    }
    else {
        $fetch = $container->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
    }

    return $container;
}
```

The function works perfectly fine when I am just using the &$container as well as $SQL arguments. But if I do that, I have to fetch the data manually. I am passing the $fetch variable by reference, because I figured that the function would fetch the data and just alter that memory location? My understanding of how this works may not be correct though.

My issue is that this function does not work with the following code:

```
$test = dbQuery($test, "Select name FROM events WHERE eventID=5083250", $testFetch, 0); echo $testFetch['name'];
```

The point where I add that to my code actually causes the rest of my page from there on and forward to stop rendering, and instead show up blank. I also get the "Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference" in my error log for this particular line of code.

Also, I wanted to add that I am aware there are several posts with the same error code, but they appear to be using BindParam and BindValue for this. I'm not sure what those exactly do, but they don't appear relevant to my issue.

Does anyone know how to properly pass two parameters by reference and modify their values?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you've passed your params in the wrong order.

Your method sig is:

```
function dbQuery(&$container, &$fetch, $fetchStatus, $SQL);
```

but you are trying to pass parameter 2, the SQL string, into `&$fetch`.

Try :

```
$test = dbQuery(
  $test,
  $testFetch,
  0,
  "Select name FROM events WHERE eventID=5083250"
)
```

Comment: Wow *facepalm*. This is embarrassing.